# How to share real time updates on a website between users on different computers?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session, ssh

I'm trying to figure out a way for users of a website (say a student and teacher) to share a secure connection where real time updates on one page are viewed by both of them.
From research I've concluded that some of the real time updates could be performed using ajax and javascript.

But I'm stumped as to how users could share a connection where only the two users would be viewing the updates that take place on the website (such as flash animations of a drawing board.) I'm also confused how you would even begin to set up a connection like this.

I've looked intp php sessions and cookies but I'm not sure I'm doing the right research. 
Any pointers as to how two specific users could share a secure connection where real time updates are viewed by the both of them only. I don't want a terse response please. I'm looking for specific details like functions and syntax specific to php. I appreciate the help and will rate you up if you give me good answers!

Comment: Are you looking for something like Google Docs, where users can see live the changes made by others? Or some shared screen application? You'll have to be more specific on what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot share a secure connection (e.g. HTTPS) its one client to one server.

If both clients are logged in and have a background AJAX task running in the browser, is it acceptable to have each client "pull" every few seconds the same data to display for both users?

This would require the "drawing board" updates to also be sent continuously back to the server to share the updated data with the other client. I'm sure there will be an event you can use to trigger the post of data (e.g. on mouse up).

If performance is an issue, you'd want to use a better server technology like Java that is able to keep session state between requests without having to persist to a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at ajax push techniques. I used comet once where an administrator posted messages and everybody who was logged in saw that message appear on their screen. I don't know if comet supports PHP. I only used it with JSP. Just search for "ajax push" in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Flash allows for connections between users, I think they refer to them as sockets.
If you want to use Ajax, et al, you need a server side technology that supports push.
Node is the standard in this regard, and you can set up a Heroku instance for free.

There are others, and you need to learn tools before even beginning to learn application.

Among the many overviews, this might interest you:
http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/05/say-hello-to-the-real-real-time-web/?1

Answer (score 0):

A few good examples where this is happening:

- [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/)
- [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/)
- [HTML5 Games: Multi player](http://html5games.com/category/multiplayer/)

Techniques you can use (with varying browser support)

- HTML5 WebSockets ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket); [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets); [HTML5 Demo](http://html5demos.com/web-socket))
- Comet ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29))

Really pushing data to a web browser client from a server (which would do that when it receives something from another client) is only possible with WebSockets as far as I know. Other mechanism would either require browser plugins or a stand-alone application.

However with Comet (through AJAX) you can get really close to pushing data by polling the server periodically for data. However contrary to traditional polling (e.g. where a clients asks for data every 5 seconds), with the Comet principle the server will hold that periodic request hostage for, say, up to 30 seconds. The server will not send back data until either it has data or the time out is reached. That way, during those 30 seconds, any data that the server receives can be instantly pushed back to the other clients. And right after that the client starts a new 30 second session, and so forth.

Although both Comet and WebSockets should work with a PHP backend served by Apache. I'd recommend looking into NodeJS (as server technology) for this.

There is a lot of information regarding Comet on the internet, I suggest you google it, maybe start at Wikipedia.

The great thing about Comet is that it is more a principle than a technology. It uses what we already have (simple HTTP requests with AJAX), so browser support is very wide.

You could also do a combination, where you use sockets if supported and fallback to Comet.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure you have looked into this. The opinion that this can be done via ajax is misleading to believe that two users of a website can communicate via javascript.

As you are aware, javascript happens on the client and ajax is essentially 'talking to the server without a page change or refresh'.

The communication between two users of the website has to happen via the server -  php and some chosen datastore.

Hope that wasn't terse.
cheers, Rob